# Euphemisms or synonyms for plagiarism

Tags: synonyms

Any funny euphemisms or synonyms for plagiarism?

Comment: "Yeah, he totally *cloned* that paper..."

Answer (score 7):

How about:

> I think Tom's paper was 'inspired' by one he found on the internet!

I also like Reg's 'borrowed'.

Perhaps also:

> I see Tom has once again stressed his green credentials, given that his paper was 'recycled' from the internet!

Or [deviating away from synonyms]

> Plagiarised? No, I was merely 'paying homage' to [the other author]!

Or

> Gandhi said that 'Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery'; I think Tom has seriously flattered another author!

Comment: Gandhi never coined any such phrase: http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/imitation-is-the-sincerest-form-of-flattery.html

Comment: Maybe he did, maybe he didn't; in the context of this question, does it matter? http://sourcesofinsight.com/gandhi-quotes/

Comment: I presume it matters to you as you quoted him... :) He definitely did not *coin* that phrase, I'm afraid.

Comment: Here's your proof: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4ZyUtKc4OmcC&vq=imitation&pg=PA127#v=snippet&q=imitation&f=false Published in 1820, 49 years before Gandhi was born.

Comment: It matters not to me or this question. It matters not whether he coined the phrase or merely was known for using it. It does matter that Ghandi *was* quoted as saying it and that my inclusion of it fits supports my answer to the question...which it does.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly great. I was merely letting you know that Gandhi did not coin the phrase you attribute to him.

Comment: In writing, the scare quotes are needed here.

Answer (score 4):

An obvious candidate would be *borrowing*. A funny-sounding one (at least to me) would be *buccaneering*.

Comment: I like *"extensive/intensive borrowing"* even more.

Comment: Along the lines of *buccaneered*: *shanghaied*. I think Tom shanghaied that paper.

Comment: "shanghai" sounds like somebody Mickey Finn'd a paper, tied it up, and squirreled it away to some abandoned warehouse... :D

Answer (score 2):

From Tom Lehrer, If memory serves:

Plagiarize! Let no one else's work evade your eyes! That's why the Good Lord made your eyes! So plagiarize, plagiarize, plagiarize! But be certain always to call it "Research".

Comment: Based on the multi-attributed quote: 'To copy from one source is plagiarism, to copy from two is research'.

Answer (score 1):

You could say of someone who has written something of dubious provenance

> If "[talent imitates and genius
>   steals](http://farisyakob.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/steve-jobs-steals.html)", then this author is a
>   genius.

The link above goes to video where Steve Jobs quotes Picasso saying "Good artists imitate, great artists steal"

Ironically, that quote is itself attributed to various people according to a page on the original wiki called [SwipedFromTheBestWithPride](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwipedFromTheBestWithPride)

> It's Picasso: "Bad artists copy. Great
>   artists steal."
>   http://www.thinkexist.com/English/Author/x/Author_3889_3.htm
>
> This has been variously attributed, in various forms, to
>   Picasso (see
>   http://quote.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Picasso),
>   Igor Stravinsky, T.S. Eliot, Sir
>   Thomas Beecham and others. Other forms
>   include:
>
> ```
> * Lesser artists borrow; great artists steal.
> * Great composers do not borrow - they steal.
> * Good artists copy; great artists steal.
> ```
>
> (Not identical but a related sentiment) Plagiarism is the sincerest form 
>   of flattery. (If you plagiarise from enough authors concurrently you get to call it "research".)

Answer (score 0):

Shephard Fairey calls it [referencing](http://www.art-for-a-change.com/Obey/index.htm)